# Json Data on Fragment

Tags: java, android, json

I am learning android programming and created a basic project using android studio.

My application crashes when I click on the `getdata` button.

The MainActivity.java:

```
package com.cs_infotech.newpathshala;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new ExampleFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Example1Fragment();

                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Example2Fragment();
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

        }    }


    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = "ePathshala";
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = "Daily Collection";
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = "New Enrolled";
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

test1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getdata"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:text="Get Data" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/getdata" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/api"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Example1Fragment.java:

```
package com.cs_infotech.newpathshala;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Example1Fragment extends Fragment {
    ListView list;
    TextView ver;
    TextView name;
    TextView api;
    Button btngetdata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/";
    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_OS = "android";
    private static final String TAG_VER = "ver";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_API = "api";
    JSONArray android = null;
    private View v;
    public Example1Fragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, container, false);
        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        btngetdata = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        v=rootView;
        btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JSONParse().execute();
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            ver = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vers);
            api = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.api);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/");
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String api = c.getString(TAG_API);
                    // Adding value HashMap key => value
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_API, api);
                    oslist.add(map);
                    list=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,
                            R.layout.list_v,
                            new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
                            R.id.vers,R.id.name, R.id.api});
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " + oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
04-10 10:12:52.253  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:com.cs_infotech.newpathshala
04-10 10:12:52.343  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-10 10:12:52.343  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala D/DisplayManager﹕ DisplayManager()
04-10 10:12:52.423  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
04-10 10:12:52.423  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11359: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
04-10 10:12:52.423  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
04-10 10:12:52.423  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
04-10 10:12:52.423  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11365: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
04-10 10:12:52.423  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
04-10 10:12:52.433  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
04-10 10:12:52.433  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9053: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
04-10 10:12:52.433  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
04-10 10:12:52.443  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
04-10 10:12:52.443  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 374: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
04-10 10:12:52.443  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-10 10:12:52.443  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
04-10 10:12:52.443  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 396: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
04-10 10:12:52.443  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-10 10:12:52.834  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-10 10:12:52.934  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41e049e0 time:9101016
04-10 10:15:04.772  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41e049e0 time:9232856
04-10 10:15:11.359  30126-30656/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416c8bc0)
04-10 10:15:11.379  30126-30656/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.cs_infotech.newpathshala, PID: 30126
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:44)
            at com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.Example1Fragment$JSONParse.doInBackground(Example1Fragment.java:80)
            at com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.Example1Fragment$JSONParse.doInBackground(Example1Fragment.java:62)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:44)
            at com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.Example1Fragment$JSONParse.doInBackground(Example1Fragment.java:80)
            at com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.Example1Fragment$JSONParse.doInBackground(Example1Fragment.java:62)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:44)
            at com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.Example1Fragment$JSONParse.doInBackground(Example1Fragment.java:80)
            at com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.Example1Fragment$JSONParse.doInBackground(Example1Fragment.java:62)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-10 10:15:12.330  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
04-10 10:15:12.360  30126-30126/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41e91890 V.E..... R......D 0,0-471,144} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:388)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.Example1Fragment$JSONParse.onPreExecute(Example1Fragment.java:74)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.cs_infotech.newpathshala.Example1Fragment$1.onClick(Example1Fragment.java:56)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 10:15:14.992  30126-30656/com.cs_infotech.newpathshala I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 30126 SIG: 9
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What's your logcat error?

Comment: post the logcat please :)

Comment: Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in AndroidManifest ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> is already added.

Comment: what is at `JSONParser.java:44`?